# Disable console window in VS2015

Tags: c++, console-application

What i want to do is to hide the console window from showing up,
I have changed my `SubSystem` to `WINDOWS` and this is my Entrypoint:

```
int APIENTRY WinMain()
{
    ...
}
```

This is the error:

> Error C2731   'WinMain': function cannot be overloaded

Also tried these:

- `HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
   ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE );`
  *This will not change anything*
- `FreeConsole();` *This will show console for a short moment then disapear*
- `#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")`*This one don't throws any error but program will not work*

Comment: You need to use the proper function definition for WinMain, The error is clear.

Comment: @RetiredNinja you mean `_stdcall WinMain` or `WINAPI WinMain`?

Comment: [Look at the definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381406(v=vs.85).aspx), provide the same arguments so the compiler doesn't have to complain.

Comment: @RetiredNinja seems it worked thank you.

Comment: @HansPassant WOW, This one also worked thank you too.